# Compact sets of direct limit topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We consider a direct limit of a tower $X_1\subset\cdots\subset X_n$ of spaces, where each $X_n$ is a subspace of $X_{n+1}$. The direct limit is $X_\infty:=\bigcup_n X_n$ endowed with the topology $\mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ defined as follows: $U\subset X_\infty$ is open if and only if $\forall n\in \Bbb{N},\quad U\cap X_n$ is open on $\mathcal{T_n}.$

We assume that $\mathcal{T}_n$ is the subspace topology on $X_n$ by $\mathcal{T_{n+1}}.$

If I denote $\mathcal{K}_n$ the family of compact sets of $X_n$ then the union of such sets are included in $K_\infty$ (which is the family of compact sets of $X_{\infty}$

If $K$ is compact of $X_n$ then it's a compact of $X_\infty.$ Do we have equality?

In other words  the collection of all compact subsets of $X_{\infty}$ is the union of the corresponding collections for each $X_n.$

**EDIT** Thanks to Eric Wofsey the answer is no if $X_{\infty}$ is not Hausdorff. What if it's Hausdorff ? (we say $T_0$?)

Comment: what is $K_\infty$, and equality between what exactly?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I edited. I hopte it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily.  For instance, suppose each $X_n$ has the indiscrete topology.  Then $X_\infty$ will also have the indiscrete topology, and every subset of $X_{\infty}$ is compact.  So as long as $X_\infty$ is not equal to $X_n$ for any $n$, then $K=X_\infty$ is a compact subset that is not contained in any $X_n$.

Comment: Thanks but here the topology on $X_{\infty}$ is not the indiscrete topology.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying; I've rephrased it to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Hum ok thanks, so we may suppose that $X_{\infty}$ is Hausdorff, right ?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easily true if every $X_n$ is open in $X_{n+1}$: then the $X_n$ will form  an open cover of $X_\infty$, so a member $K$ of $K_\infty$ is covered by finitely hence by one $X_n$, and so $K \subseteq X_n$ for some $n$.